# Facing issues while running test class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a class to upload attachments. I wrote a test class for code coverage but it is failing and giving below error.

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Sorry if it is a easy question :( I just started to learn test classes

Here is My code

**Class** :

```
Public Pagereference Saveattachment()
    {
        String aid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');

        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = aid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);


         try {
         insert a;
          }
         catch (DMLException e) {
          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error !!'));
          return null;

         }


        return NULL;
    }
```

**Test Class :**

```
static testMethod void testmethod1(){

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        insert acc;
        Attachment attach=new Attachment();     
        attach.Name=' Attachment';
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Attachment Body');
        attach.body=bodyBlob;
        attach.parentId=acc.id;
        insert attach; 
        PageReference pageRef = Page.closedateQuickaction;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(acc);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',acc.id);

        classAttachment at = new classAttachment(sc);
        at.Saveattachment();

        System.assertEquals(attach.parentId,acc.id);

    }
```

Comment: Which line is it throwing null exception ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks for your response it is throwing at  at.Saveattachment();

Comment: Logs will tell you which line in saveAttachment() is throwing error .Please check logs

Comment: It is throwing error @ Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = aid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized "myfile", so trying to access a member of it is not valid. Looks like you should change your code to:

```
static testMethod void testmethod1(){

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        insert acc;
        PageReference pageRef = Page.closedateQuickaction;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(acc);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',acc.id);

        classAttachment at = new classAttachment(sc);
        at.myfile = new Attachment(Body=Blob.valueOf('Attachment Body'), Name='some name');
        at.Saveattachment();
        Attachment attach = [SELECT ParentId FROM Attachment];
        System.assertEquals(attach.parentId,acc.id);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Point of failure is  myfile variable

You can remove insert attachment from your code as you want to test the insertion via method invoke ,so your test code should not be inserting the attachment and instead just instantiating it and your method invoked via test code will insert which you can assert after test execution

If it needs to be set,please set the variable in your controller like

```
at.myfile = new Attachment(Body=Blob.valueOf('Test String'), Name='Test file');

at.Saveattachment();
```

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't cause a null pointer exception...

Comment: Just updated the answer.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks for providing solution !!

Answer (score 1):

This look suspicious: "name=*myfile.name*"  I would look to see if 'myfile' is a class level variable that was never initialized.

For thorough debugging, you should add "system.debug(loggingLevel.info, )" in your SaveAttachment method.  For example:

```
system.debug(loggingLevel.info, 'myfile = ' + myfile);
```